# Replacement of the complex character string

Tags: java, android

The string is "hi\how \ r\ u\" and need to replace "\" with the space.

String stringToModify =  "hi\how \ r\ u\";

stringToModify = stringToModify .replace("\\", "");

System.out.println(stringToModify );

Comment: What do you mean by "" character?

Comment: The empty string is *not* a character. It's an empty sequence of characters. It's also unclear whether you're trying to remove actual backslashes, or carriage returns and line feeds. If you could produce a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem, it would be a lot easier to help you.

Comment: no, it's very much clear from the question that "\" need to be replace with "" i.e empty sequence of characters... so, what you need further.. anyway remove the -1 from the question...

Comment: The question is anything but clear - it's not obvious whether the string you've given is meant to be a Java string literal containing carriage return and line feed, or the actual contents of a string containing a backslash and an "r" (etc). As it happens, I hadn't downvoted before - but as you refuse to improve the question, I will do so now. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints for suggestions on how to write questions clearly. If you want to provide a short but complete program (which I strongly encourage) it needn't be anything to do with Android - this is a plain Java question.

Comment: can't you see the tag for android and java

Comment: Yes - which is why I bothered to state that it actually has nothing to do with Android. Both the question and the answer can be written with no reference to Android. Now how about you stop being rude, and simply clarify the question as requested?

Comment: ok, anyway I found the solution at the same time after posting these question.. anyway thank's for your concern...

Comment: The sad thing is that I suspect you haven't learned anything about asking questions well. *Please* read the link I gave a few comments ago before asking questions in future.

Comment: so, according to you what should be the question.. now you have understand the main theme of the question.. now you can suggest me the question.

Comment: No, I still don't know exaclty what your string contained before or what you wanted afterwards. You seem to have rejected the perfectly good answers to the most likely interpretation of the question, leaving me in the dark. A short but complete program demonstrating the problem would remove all doubt. That would be the single biggest improvement you could make.

Comment: These is the string "hi\how \ r\ u\" and I would like to remove '\' that's all...

Comment: Then it should be easy to show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, shouldn't it? And you shouldn't need to be rude to people who've given working answers... Given that you were unclear that an empty string isn't a character, it wasn't at all clear (and I'm still not 100% convinced) that you understand the difference between a Java string literal where `\` represents escaping, and the *contents* of a Java string which contains genuine backslashes. *That* is what a short but complete program would make crystal clear.

Comment: thank's for your suggestion and guidelines... so, sorry for any mis-concept against you... can we be a friend...

Comment: No problem, of course. Just trying to hammer in the value of using code to demonstrate the problem. It makes an *enormous* difference in the answerability of questions :)

Comment: ok anyway can I get your mail id and please can you tell me the difference between '' and "". Waiting for your reply..

Comment: If you just look at my profile you can find out my email address... but basically single quotes are used for *character* literals and double quotes are used for *string* literals.

Comment: ok thank's for your ans.. and can you please revert the -ve point one these question.. actually it's restrict me too further post the question....

Comment: Sure - just edit the question to make it a good question...

Comment: actually you have such a great profile... I like it. anyway nice taking with you sir...

Comment: u didn't remove my -ve point till now.. please do it..

Comment: Nope - 'cos it's still a bad question. I suggested *several* changes to make it a better question, and you haven't done any of them.

Comment: No idea... I hv found the answer also.. but it's very hard to make u satisfied with the question... u can suggest me the question I will make it edit.. right...

Comment: I've suggested *several* times that you write a short but complete program that demonstrates the problem, and you still haven't. I've suggested that you read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints, but there's no indication that you've done so given the state of your question. That link gives you all the suggestions you need.

Comment: I think now I have edit the question according to your expectation...

Comment: Nope - "empty space" is somewhat ambiguous: an empty string, or a space? And you *still* don't have a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: That's not complete, not formatted as code, and doesn't compile (you're using `str` then `s`, you're missing a semi-colon, and the string literal is invalid). I don't know whether or not it would demonstrate the problem, because it doesn't compile.

Comment: It's still incomplete. It still won't compile. It's still not formatted as code. I don't understand why you haven't at *least* fixed the compilation problem... get some code which compiles, and then post that. Do you not have easy access to a Java compiler which would tell you that your string literal is invalid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
yourString = yourString.replace("\\", "");
```

**EDIT:**

```
String s = "hi\\how \\ r\\ u\\"; // which is actually "hi\how \ r\ u\"
s = s.replace("\\", "");
System.out.println(s); // prints "hihow  r u"
```

Comment: please first execute your self then give the respond.... because I already check these things....

Comment: @kamal Nobody is here to do coding for you he has just given the idea how to accomplish you have to try it by your self

Comment: ok, thank's guy's for your concern.. I exactly get what you really mean thank's once again...

Answer (score 3):

```
yourString = yourString.replace("\\", "\"\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need additional slashes if you want to define the string by typing into your script.

```
var str="hi\\how \\ r\\ u\\";
// This will basicly become "hi\how \ r\ u\" in memory
```

When I try this script

```
var str="hi\how \ r\ u\\";                          
document.writeln(str+"</br>"); 
document.writeln(str.replace("\\", "")+"</br>"); 
document.write(str.split("\\").join("")+"</br>");

var str="hi\\how \\ r\\ u\\";
document.writeln(str+"</br>"); 
document.writeln(str.replace("\\", "")+"</br>"); 
document.write(str.split("\\").join("")+"</br>");
```

Then i'm getting this output. Its strange to understand.

- hihow r u\  <-- all single slashes is ignored
- hihow r u   <-- first mach of "\" was at end
- hihow r u   <-- split/join will do the same with the single slash
- hi\how \ r\ u\   <-- this is the actual str you want to work with
- hihow \ r\ u\    <-- first mach of "\" was after hi
- hihow r u        <-- split/join will remove all slashes

It looks like split then joining works best in this case. Otherwis you need to put the replace function into a loop. But first of all you have to define the string you want to work with correctly.

```
var str="hi\\how \\ r\\ u\\";
str.split("\\").join("")
```

Comment: please first execute it then after respond... and the code that you mention is not acceptable in java. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Thats right.. You can't have "\" at end if you define it as in above.. So you may remove it manually.. even this will work then
var str="hi\how \ r\ u"; 
document.write(str);

Comment: You need additional slashes if you want to define the string in your script. It looks like the replace-function replaces only the first match. And when you use single slashes in a string definition then theye are ignored in java unless you use \n, \t, \r etc...

Comment: This answers is JavaScript, not Java.

Comment: I know that this is in JavaScript. If you can't get the point then you should quit programming and begin cooking I think..

Comment: You can't define your string like this "hi\how \ r\ u\" in Java or JavaScript or whatever else. The "\" character is reserved for defining special characters as tab linefeed etc.. (\n, \r, \t, \xx) That why you need double backslashes if you want to define it inside your script. "\\". Single backslash will also ignore the next caracter normally. like in str="kamal sayed: \"what?\"".  Either you have to use double slashes or you have to read it from a textfile etc..